# Ubuntu 18.04 does not start after upgrade from Ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, boot, grub2, upgrade, 18.04

I had just finished upgrading, and now, when I restarted the system to complete the installation process, Ubuntu does not start.

The boot menu and GRUB work fine, leading me to the boot menu when I request it. But instead of booting, the system is stuck at a frozen light grey screen bound by a darker grey border. I tried entering recovery mode, but it doesn't work. What am I supposed to do now?

The upgrade process ended, but I remember reading a line which said that there were errors. How should I solve this problem?

By the way, I have NVIDIA drivers installed, and recently I had been experimenting with KVM virtual machines.

EDIT: I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@calerogers/gpu-virtualization-with-kvm-qemu-63ca98a6a172), which was a failed attempt at trying to transfer the GPU to a virtual machine instance that ran on KVM. Do you think I could have messed up something there?

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to solve the problem. It was the NVIDIA drivers after all. I couldn't access the terminal in any way. So, I had use the liveCdRecovery method to gain access to the system (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery#Update_Failure):

```
#Boot the Ubuntu Live CD.

#Press Ctrl-Alt-F1

sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev

sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc

sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

sudo chroot /mnt
```

This basically gives access to the 'terminal', from the context of the system that has to be repaired. And that's it! I used purge on the NVIDIA drivers, and the system finally booted.